# Compiling error for python script to exe using py2exe and pyttsx

Tags: python, py2exe

I have a python script that I made and it uses pyttsx for text to speech output. Whenever I converted it to an exe using py2exe and tried running the exe I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "pyttsx\__init__.pyc", line 39, in init
  File "pyttsx\engine.pyc", line 45, in __init__
  File "pyttsx\driver.pyc", line 66, in __init__
  File "pyttsx\drivers\sapi5.pyc", line 37, in buildDriver
  File "pyttsx\drivers\sapi5.pyc", line 46, in __init__
  File "win32com\client\__init__.pyc", line 317, in WithEv
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CLSID'
```

Here is a copy of my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console=['main.py'],
    options = {
        "py2exe":{
            "includes":[
                'pyttsx.drivers.sapi5'
            ]
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

YEY - I got it working!

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

py2exe_options = { 'includes': ['pyttsx.drivers.sapi5', 'win32com.gen_py.C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628x0x5x4'],
                   'typelibs': [('{C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628}', 0, 5, 4)] }

setup(console=['main.py'], options = {'py2exe': py2exe_options})
```

Note though that this requires you to run the same version (v5.4 in my case) on both machines. If you want to circumvent that you probably need to try something [more advanced](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/IncludingTypelibs).

Answer (score 0):

You should try running with pyttsx3 and use your system's text to speech api like sapi 5 for windows. Its much faster and more recent.